# A bug in UILocalNotification - a too distant notification crashes

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

Please be aware that in `UILocalNotification`, if you try to set the notification in the distant future, the system crashes. So you need to restrict the ability of the user to enter such dates.
Enjoy

Comment: this is logical consistent. Nobody will live long enough to receive the notification ;-)

Comment: Of course, but users can make mistakes inadvertently